# Checking hardware virtualization with a locked BIOS?

Tags: bios, virtualization

I want to buy a used laptop with a locked BIOS, whose password can't be reset by removing the RTC battery (HP EliteBook). So in case the previous owner had it enabled, how can I confirm? Windows 7 OS.

Comment: boot a live linux cd and check cpu features

Comment: @user993553 I know cpu supports it, but you need to enable it in BIOS, to increase performance, I think.

Comment: Also, I can access the Windows with a locked BIOS.

Comment: linux does not report the vmx if disabled in bios see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-xen-vmware-kvm-intel-vt-amd-v-support/

Comment: @user993553 Thanks. Easy solution.

Comment: @user993553 I have to ask, is there any way to enable it without BIOS?

Comment: No, bios access is mandatory